# vue 's v-show doesn't show up as expected

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using vue to make a menu which can show and hide the description when click the title.

The original menu is like this showing the title

[image: The original menu]

The expanded menu is like this expanding the menu description

[image]

```
<li class="cursor-pointer p-2 flex"  v-for="(menu, index) in menus" :key="index" >
    <div class="w-full flex  items-center justify-between px-2" @click="handleSelect(menu,index)">  
        <div  class="text-sm w-full ">
            <i class="el-icon-document" ></i> {{ menu.name }} 
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- menu show and hide-->
    <ul  class="py-4 px-1  rounded-b border-gray-100" v-show="menu.showed">
        {{ menu.description }} 
    </ul>
</li>

handleSelect(menu,index){
    console.log('select',index,menu.showed);
    this.menus[index].showed=!menu.showed
},    

menus:[
    { 
      name:'Introduction',
      showed: false,
      decription:''
    },
    { 
      name:'Feedback Is Important',
      showed: false,
      decription:''
    }, 
    { 
      name:'Client Briefing and Debriefing',
      showed: false,
      decription:''
    },                                                                          
]
```

my expected result is that the expanded status of the menu could show and hide when clicking the menu title.  However, clicking the first menu could change the 'showed' variable but doesn't show the expansion, only clicking the second menu will show the first menu.

It seems like the v-show not working, any solution or idea to solve it or better way to deal with menu show-up.

Answer (score 0):

Your data needs to be `reactive`.  Put your menus array inside the `data` section when using options API , or inside a `setup script` when using composition API

Comment: My menu data is in the data section

Comment: Have you tried `v-if`?